# Usage of Agda Data.Bool solver

Tags: agda

I've tried to use Agda Data.Bool solver in Agda version 2.6.1-4e989c1

```
module example where

  open import Data.Bool hiding ( _∨_ )
  open import Relation.Binary
  open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

  open import Data.Bool.Solver using (module xor-∧-Solver)
  open xor-∧-Solver

  problem0' :  ( Cat : Bool ) → (Cat xor Cat ) ≡ false
  problem0' = solve 1 (λ c → (c :+ c ) := con false ) refl
```

so far so good.

```
  problem1' :  ( Cat : Bool ) → (Cat ∧ (Cat xor true ))  ≡ false
  problem1' = solve 1 (λ c → ((c :* (c :+ con true )) ) := con false ) ?
```

Putting `refl` in the ?, give us a very long conflict including `Data.Vec.Vec.[])
!=< false of type Bool`. Am I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for the normalized goal (most commands relating to goal printing can be prefixed by `C-u C-u` to show the normal form of the output) you will get:

```
{x : Bool} → (x xor true) ∧ x xor false ≡ false
```

which is how far the solver was able to "simplify" the problem.

I could be wrong, but this equality doesn't seem to follow from just the laws of commutative rings, which is what the solver works with.

A solver specific to `Bool` could take advantage of the extra structure, or even just case split if there aren't too many variables.